# hiding a button in html

Tags: javascript, html

I want to hide a button on the click of another button. So i checked some  questions on stack overflow . I used display property and assigned it to hidden. And now I want to unhide it on the click of another button.

I want to increment variable "a" on the click of button1. and when the variable a is greater or equal to three i want to unhide 'button' (The button which has id #again) which is hidden. That means after clicking in button1 twice i want to unhide the button. But It is not working. No mater how many times i click in the button1, it is not working.I used display property and made it to hidden in the html file.

Could anybody say what i want to do here in order to unhide the button when clicked on the button1 twice.

```js
let a = 1;
let button = document.querySelector("#again");
let button1 = document.querySelector("#again1");
button1.onclick = () => {
  a++;
}
if (a >= 3) {
  button.style.display = "block";
}
```

```html
<button id="again" style="display:none;">click me</button>
<button id="again1">here</button>
<script src="practise.js"></script>
```

Comment: Move the `if (...)` inside the onclick function you define for the button.

Comment: spelling mistake too

Comment: `onClick()` is written wrong.

Comment: Sorry. Its working now. Thanks for replying. The mistake was the spelling. So Sorry

Answer (score 2):

Your `if` block is calculated just once in the beginning when the browser parses through the js file. Instead, you want to check it every time `button1` is clicked. Move it inside the event listener.

```js
let a = 1;
let button = document.querySelector("#again");
let button1 = document.querySelector("#again1");
button1.onclick = () => {
  a++
  if (a >= 3) {
    button.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="again" style="display:none;">click me</button>
<button id="again1">here</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

1. spelling onclick
2. if needs to go inside the function

```js
let a = 1;
let button = document.querySelector("#again");
let button1 = document.querySelector("#again1");
button1.onclick = () => {
  a++;
  if (a >= 3) {
    button.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="again" style="display:none;">click me</button>
<button id="again1">here</button>
<script src="practise.js"></script>
```

Alternative using eventListener and hidden

```js
let a = 1;
let button = document.querySelector("#again");
let button1 = document.querySelector("#again1");
button1.addEventListener("click", () => {
  a++;
  button.hidden = a < 3
})
```

```html
<button id="again" hidden>click me</button>
<button id="again1">here</button>
<script src="practise.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put the if condition inside the `onClick()` function .

```js
let a = 1;
let button = document.querySelector("#again");
let button1 = document.querySelector("#again1");
button1.onclick = () => {
  a++
  if (a > 2) {
    button.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="again" style="display:none;">click me</button>
<button id="again1">here</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple:

```js
var button = document.getElementById("again1")
let button1 = document.querySelector("#again");
count = 0;
button.onclick = function() {
  count += 1;
  if (count >= 3) {
    button1.style.display = "block";
  }
  button.innerHTML = "Click me: " + count;
};
```

```html
<button id="again" style="display:none;">click me</button>
<button id="again1">here</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here in the above responses 'display: hidden' means it will occupy the space in UI where as 'display: none' means it won't occupy the space. Now you can decide which one to use as well

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).